# Сериализация/Десериализация объекта в java

Tags: java, android, сериализация

Сериализирую объект в файл на Android таким образом:

```
FileOutputStream fos = getApplicationContext().openFileOutput("order.dat", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
order = new Order(serverPass, purchase.getText().toString(), new Date(), name.getText().toString(), logInEmail, null, null, null, listSelectNom, null, listSelectIt);
 oos.writeObject(order);

oos.flush();
oos.close();
fos.close();

final File file = new File(getFilesDir(), "order.dat");
```

Далее передаю файл - file через сокет на ПК.
ПК в свою очередь принимает и десериализирует файл обратно в объект:

```
File file = new File("order.dat");
FileOutputStream fOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);
BufferedInputStream bufferInput = new BufferedInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
int fileSize = bufferInput.read(buffer);
fOutput.write(buffer, 0, fileSize);

FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(file);
ObjectInputStream objectInput = new ObjectInputStream(fileInput);
order = (Order) objectInput.readObject();
```

При этом файл десериализируется неправильно.
Если файл десереализирую в Android то всё проходит успешно:

```
Order order1;
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
order1= (Order) is.readObject();
is.close();
```

Что я делаю неправильно? Файл принимается нормально, ошибок при отправке и приеме не выдаёт. Как сделать правильную десереализацию в приложении на ПК?

Comment: Что значит "десериализируется неправильно"?

Comment: Ну после принятия и дессериализации объекта у меня должен появиться объект класса Order, из которого я могу вытащить какие либо переменные с помощью get, которые прописаны в классе объекта, а их там просто нет.

Comment: Попробуйте сериализировать и обратно с помощью Gson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вомзожно проблема в `Context.MODE_PRIVATE`

> int MODE_PRIVATE File creation mode: the default mode, where the
>   created file can only be accessed by the calling application (or all
>   applications sharing the same user ID).

Файл созданный с такой меткой может быть открыт только тем же приложением или другим приложение с таким же ID

Comment: Исправил на MODE_APPND, не помогло((( Заметил, что сервер выдаёт исключение java.io.EOFException со значением null в этом месте:

     order = (Order) objectInput.readObject();